# while tryying to run 'rails s', why does it fail and ask to INSTALL gem 'therubyracer' to use Less

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, therubyracer

I was able to load everything to start using Twitter bootstrap on my ROR application. I even loaded 'therubyracer' gem. Its a windows machine and it seems there are many that have had issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the following gems in `Gemfile` and set the version of `twitter-bootstrap-rails` then `bundle install` :-

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", '2.2.6'
#gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
#gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
```

As on windows `therubyracer` and `less-rails` gems are not required.